# Known results about maximum size of a code with minimum hamming distance K

Tags: coding-theory

Let $W(r,n)$ be the set of all words of length $r$ on $n$ letters.

For two words $a,b \in W(r,n)$ define the Hamming distance $d(a,b)$ as the number of places that they have different letters.

Let $M(r,n,k)$ be the maximum $|S|$ such that $S \subseteq W(r,n)$ and $\forall a,b \in S$ $d(a,b) \ge k$ (I believe this is usually denoted $A_n(r,k)$ in coding theory)

Most of the results I have seen about this value have been in the case $n=2$ since most applications of this idea are in binary codes.  I am not particularly interested in $n=2$ and am wondering if any general bounds are known (lower or upper) or even a list of known exact values for small numbers would be nice.  I do know that the Singelton bound says $M(r,n,k) \le n^{r-k+1}$.  Any other information you could give me would be greatly appreciated.  General bounds or exact values are good, or even if $M(r,n,k)$ has a "name" attached to it?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many upper bounds that work in the generality you are asking, in addition to the Singleton bound. E.g. the Plotkin and Hamming bounds. For a lower bound, there is the Gilbert-Varshamov bound. Tightening these bounds is of course a well known old wide open problem, so if you want something more specific, you need to narrow your question a bit.

Comment: Thank you I will read up on those. Are you aware of anything about exact values?

Comment: often Delsarte (linear programming) is quite good. You can look up upper/lower bounds for small tuples of parameters in http://codetables.de/, and compute them with Sagemath or Magma.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I got the impression the question was for non-linear codes.

Comment: A few questions I have after reading about some of these things on Wikipedia.  First of all what makes a code "linear?", To me it is just a collection of words with no other structure than a minimum distance of K. There is obviously some heavy duty algebra at work behind the scenes but it doesn't really come out and say it.  Also most of the theorems seem to assume, or discuss as a special case, that the alphabet is a finite field.  I have no reason to impose such a restriction but it may provide insight if I knew why that case is special.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Elliot Most bounds for codes $C$, even if they are stated and proven for linear codes, work for non-linear codes over finite alphabets of size $q$ as well, except that one has to replace $\dim C$ with $\log|C|/\log q$. A notable exception is the Griesmer bound, which truly uses the linearity of the code.

Comment: So there doesn't seem to be much in the way of equality so the following result I have proven should be fairly interesting:

Comment: If $n$ is a prime number and is sufficiently large compared to $r$ and $k$, then $M(r,n,k)$ obtains the singleton bound.  Now the sufficiently large condition I came up with is pretty enormous but is based on some pretty crude approximations so I suspect it holds for much smaller $n$

Comment: I have also been looking at small values and have that $M(r,n,3)$ obtains the singelton bound for all odd $n \ge 3$. The even case has been much more difficult but I recently showed $M(4,3,3) = 16$,  again the singelton bound. I am trying to see if I can generalize that construction to other evens

Comment: If $n$, the size of the alphabet, is a prime power (in particular prime) and sufficiently large (bigger than the length $r$ is enough), then the Singleton bound is attained by the Reed-Solomon codes. This has been known since the 1960s.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch: linear programming bounds hold for nonlinear codes just as well, and Sagemath can compute these for you. Regarding tables of nonlinear codes and bounds, one can check the page http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/ of Andries Brouwer for links.